# FFMPEG Formating all videos in a folder to be the same for concating

Tags: bash, video, ffmpeg

Ok so I'm trying to make a programm that takes the mp4 files in a folder and formats them to be the same ratio and framerate to simplify concating.

This is what I have so far.

```
#!/bin/bash
NUMBER=0
MP=".mp4"
OUT="./Media/Rescaled/"
for filename in ./Media/*.mp4; do
    echo "$filename"
    NAME=$(basename "$filename" .mp4)
    NEWNAME=$NAME$NUMBER$MP
    let "NUMBER += 1"
    ffmpeg -i "$filename" -y -r 24 -vf scale=640:640  $OUT$NEWNAME
done
```

I receive 2 errors that I can't really get my head around as of now:

```
The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled,                 
add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.
```

which I first of all am not sure where to put in and second of all have heard it messes with audio quality and

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x19434c0] Format mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2  
detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!

[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x19434c0] moov atom not found
./Media/Whitenoise.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

I am absolutely a novice at this, so I would appreciate answers with an explanation or pointing me to something that explains it well as I've been having trouble finding good ffmpeg material.

Thanks for reading through this!

Comment: have you tried the solution suggested by the 1st error message ? try `ffmpeg -strict -2 -i ...`

Comment: doing that doesn't remove the error, which I find weird but still

Comment: Your `ffmpeg` is ancient. Upgrade and it will get rid of the "experimental" error message. Recent builds for Linux: https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/